# Why is 'sales order place after' observer not executed in 1.9.1 but it is in 1.8.0

Tags: orders, event-observer, ce-1.9.1.0, ce-1.8.0.0

I have created a module for listening to the event `sales_order_place_after`. I did it following the article [http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout](http://www.atwix.com/magento/auto-invoice-and-custom-order-status-upon-checkout/).

I use it for set my order to processing status, because it's always changed to pending that I set with new order status.

The module works in Magento 1.8.0, but it doesn't work in magento 1.9.1. How could I resolve this problem? Please help me

This is how the module is built:

1. First, I create a module initializer in /app/etc/modules/Atwix_Orderhook.xml with following content

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Atwix_Orderhook>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>community</codePool>
           </Atwix_Orderhook>
       </modules>
   </config>
   ```
2. then I create a module configuration file  /app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/etc/config.xml with content

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <modules>
           <Atwix_Orderhook>
               <version>1.0</version>
           </Atwix_Orderhook>
       </modules>

       <global>

           <models>            
               <orderhook>
                   <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model</class>
               </orderhook>
           </models>

           <events>
               <sales_order_place_after>
                   <observers>
                       <auto_invoice_order>
                           <type>singleton</type>
                           <class>Atwix_Orderhook_Model_Observer</class>
                           <method>implementOrderStatus</method>
                       </auto_invoice_order>
                   </observers>
               </sales_order_place_after>
           </events>

       </global>
   </config>
   ```
3. finally I create the app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/Observer.php with following content

   ```
   <?php

   class Atwix_Orderhook_Model_Observer 
   {
       public function implementOrderStatus($event)
       {
           $order = $event->getOrder();
           if ($this->_getPaymentMethod($order) == 'cwinline') {
               $this->_processOrderStatus($order);
           }
           return $this;
       }

       private function _getPaymentMethod($order){        {
           return $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode();
       }

       private function _processOrderStatus($order){
           $status = $order->getPayment()->getStatus();
           if($status=='SUCCESS'){
               $this->_changeOrderStatus($order);
           }
           return true;
       }

       private function _changeOrderStatus($order){
       $statusMessage = 'payment success';
       $order->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_PROCESSING,$statusMessage, false);        
       $order->save();
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: it's hard to pinpoint the issue without looking at the code, are you using the code exactly as it shows on the article? Do you get any error in the logs? The event name is the same in 1.9.1 so the must be something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: I will update my question right now,hold on please.

Comment: It's done.Now Im going to take a look at the log.

Comment: there is no exception both in system.log and exception.log.

Comment: Path of the observer is wrong, it should be app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/Model/Observer.php, You are missing Model

Comment: oh yes,it just is! thank for your help,best wishes!

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz, please write your comment as an answer as it provides the solution to the OP's question. Thanks!

Comment: @NasirPerwaiz, agree with **7ochem**, you should write it as answer, then OP can mark it as correct answer if that has helped him. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

As suggested by 7ochem and Adarsh Khatri I am writing my answer,
The path to your observer Model is wrong. It should be,

```
app/code/community/Atwix/Orderhook/Model/Observer.php
```

Answer (score 1):

The  node in your config.xml file should be placed in a new

```
<frontend> node under </global>
```